# Angular 11 through error when install angular-mention

Tags: angular, angular11, mention

I am trying to use angular-mention in angular version 11. getting errors like

```
Error: node_modules/angular-mentions/lib/mention.module.d.ts:6:21 - error TS2694: Namespace '"<project path>/node_modules/@angular/core/core"' has no exported member 'ɵɵFactoryDeclaration'.
```

Here are the dependencies packages in my application

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/localize": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^7.2.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^19.0.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "angular-gridster2": "^11.2.0",
    "angular-mentions": "^1.5.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "ng-click-outside": "^9.0.0",
    "ng2-toasty": "^4.0.3",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^12.0.3",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.4.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "screenfull": "^5.1.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.4",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~11.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.7",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
```

I have already tried to remove and reinstall node_modules, but still, the error is showing.

Comment: Which library version are you trying to install? This error looks like Ivy compatibility issue. Try version 1.3.0